# How to setup DDR Menu Settings in DNN

Tags: menu, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I have looked at the DNN DDR Menu Wiki and can't seem to figure out how to set the DDR Menu Module settings. Can someone please answer with a screenshot with their settings so that I can get an idea of how exactly you specify everything?

I had a look at the following web pages:

1. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-user-guide
2. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/440954/scope/posts/ddr-module-menu-settings
3. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/ddr-module-menu-settings-to-show-dept-child-pages
4. https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-reference-guide

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only "required" setting is Menu Style. This refers to the "template" for the menu.

Take a look at https://dnndocs.com/content/guides/tutorials/theme-objects/ddrmenu/index.html and also https://dnncommunity.org.

dnncommunity is where the action these days, ad the DNN Community lead the development of the DNN Platform.